# Testing a method producing a random result

Tags: java, random, junit

I want to test this method:`ArrayList<File> songs;`

```
public void playRandomSong()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int iNextSong = random.nextInt(songs.size());
    File songToPlay = songs.get(iNextSong);
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayerImpl(songToPlay, new WhenDone());
    mediaPlayer.play();
    currentSong = songToPlay;
}
```

I'm thinking in this way: Run the method multiple times and see if it returns one of the elements more than once. But how would I write that in code?

Comment: No problem, the method works as it should. But im quite new to programming and now im trying to learn unit testing. And thats why i want to write a test for this method. My mediaplayer only play every song once. So what i mean is that, if if returns one of the element more than once, then the test should pass. Is it maybe possible to have a counter for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random does not guarantee that it will not return the same value twice...
So you can not test `"see if it returns one of the elements more than once"`

If you need that you will have to implement a `Set` around the `Random`, but be aware of the Birthday paradox...

I think you have 2 options:

1 : You may try to seed your `Random`, so you can predict the sequence...

2 : Remove the Random and make use of the `[Collections.shuffle][1]` to shuffle you arrayList

With Option 1 you will have to change the signature of your method.

With Option 2 you will also play every song once.

Comment: My mediaplayer only play every song once. So what i mean is that, if if returns one of the element more than once, then the test should pass. Is it maybe possible to have a counter for this?

Comment: As i said, Random does not guarantee this, you will have to program it like that.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a RNG in your method

```
public void playRandomSong() {
  Random random = new Random();
  ...
}
```

you should pass the source of randomness in (this is called *dependency injection*)

```
public void playRandomSong(Random random) {
  ...
}
```

and then you can generate a `Random` instance with a known seed in your unit test to get repeatable but typical results.

```
public void testPlayRandomSong() {
  Random random = new Random(0xd5021e90339050ab);

  // Test that 1000 runs plays each song roughly the right number of times.
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see another problem in your code: if you want to play songs in random order you are doing that in wrong way. This algorithm should not repeat song until all songs in list are played. To achieve that there is an algorithm called Knuth shuffling. You can take it from `Collections` class: [`java.util.Collections#shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on randomness testing that you might find useful:

http://beust.com/weblog/2012/02/20/various-ways-to-get-randomness-wrong/